# Live inspections in PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm, inspection

I created some buggy Python code on purpose:

```
foo = 3
if foo != None:
    print("bar")
```

Then PyCharm underlines the comparison, warning that it's not the way I should compare against `None`.

But I'd like to have a list of all problems with my code (just as in Eclipse). I activate the `View > Tool windows > Inspection results` but this problem is not listed until I manually re-run inspections. When I fix another problem from the inspection report, the inspection window is not updated either.

What can I do so that the inspections list is updated when I edit my code? Or maybe I have enabled the wrong thing?